# Are Cardassians physically stronger than humans?

Tags: star-trek

Is it ever discussed or revealed if Cardassians are generally stronger than humans? I would think they are since humans seem to be pretty weak when compared to many other races (klingons, vulcans, etc.) Where do the Cardassians rank in physical strength?

Comment: I dont think it was ever discussed on the show.  For most purposes they were human analogues.

Comment: "It was never discussed" is a valid answer to this.

Comment: I can't quite remember details but I'm sure relevant strength was discussed whilst Whorf was captured by the Jem H'dar and forced to fight his captors (DS9) - I'm sure the cardassians were involved (conversations/fights). Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: @queeg - a doped-up injured butterfly [could beat Worf](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33471/why-does-worf-always-lose-fights-and-get-beaten-by-most-of-his-opponents).

Comment: Most races are stronger than humans. I assume this is to highlight that humans use brains over brawn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within the TV show, there aren't any specific conversations about Cardassian physical strength, nor are there any special mentions in the general reference material about the Cardassians being stronger or weaker than humans (or any other race, for that matter).

There are numerous scenes of the Cardassians in fights with humans. Sisko punches Dukat, Dukat is dragged from his office, Sisko punches Garak, various guards are beaten up by Federation soldiers, etc etc. In each of these encounters, the Cardassians show no overt physicality, all of which tends toward the the conclusion that their physical strength is unremarkable by human standards.

[image]

---

Moving down the canon scale, within the EU the Cardassians are generally portrayed as having no exceptional strength. The [Cardassian RPG sourcebook](http://stexpanded.wikia.com/wiki/Cardassian_Sourcebook) gives them no additional points for strength compared to human-normal and the various novels make no reference to their strength.

in "[Emissary](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Emissary_(novel))", O'Brien fights a Cardassian and is pushed backwards by a Cardassian soldier:

> Movement: a black-sleeved arm sweeping across his field of vision,
>   knocking the phaser from his hand. O’Brien reached out blindly, seeing
>   nothing now but rage and hate, and caught one of the Cardassian’s
>   wrists, then the other, roaring as he slammed the alien into the wall.
>   The air rushed from the Cardassian’s lungs with a loud gasp. O’Brien
>   seized the hand that held the phaser, pinned it against the wall and
>   then slammed it again and again, until the weapon clattered to the
>   floor.
>
> With a surge of strength, the Cardassian pushed. O’Brien staggered
>   backwards, stumbled over a wailing child, and lost his footing. The
>   Cardassian scrabbled for his weapon.

In the Mirror Universe Novel "[Shards and Shadows](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Shards_and_Shadows)", Keiko is pushed and lifted by a cardassian guard. There is no mention that she's surprised by his abilities:

> A Cardassian guard she knew by sight but not by name reached down to
>   grab her arm. He pulled her to her feet. Keiko got her legs underneath
>   her and used the Cardassian’s arm to help steady herself.
>
> The Cardassian pushed her against the wall. “Explain yourself.”

later

> He pushed her against the wall and kissed her. She responded by
>   dropping her tools and wrapping her arms around his neck. She leaned
>   into his kiss.

Answer (score -2):

They never say, although Cardassians seem to be much weaker than Bajorans - Kira, a 90-pound Bajoran female, is able to kick the asses of at least a couple different male Cardassias.  And those were soldiers, not a tailor - Sisko kicked Garak's ass.  Since Bajorans were never shown to be any stronger than humans, I assume a human is also much stronger than a Cardassian.

Comment: Although we have to assume that Kira had extensive training in hand-to-hand combat, Bajoran and/or Federation martial arts, etc.. All of which would enable her to "punch well above her weight", so to speak - that she has a skills advantage over her Cardassian opponents, making up for any disadvantage in physicality.

Comment: -1; citation needed for Kira/Nana Visitor's weight.

Comment: @ToddJones Insults are against the [code of conduct](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/conduct) and will not be tolerated.

Answer (score -3):

There is a scene in DS9, where humans are described as having superior auditory abilities... we also have a higher tolerance to cold opposed to Cardassians and Vulcans.

Comment: That doesn't really seem to address whether Cardassians are physically stronger.

Comment: Also human's invented pizza, yay humans